# Linear system the algebraic curve $y^2=x^6-1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the Riemann surface associated to the curve $y^2=x^6-1$ realized as a branched covering of $\mathbb{P}^1$. Let $r_{\alpha}=(e^{\alpha\pi i/3},0)$ and $p+q=\pi^{-1}(\infty)$. I need to find the complete linear system $|r_0+r_2+r_4|$ and the divisor $D$ on $\mathcal{C}$ s.t. $D+r_1\sim r_0+r_2+r_4$ (linearly equivalent). I have tried to find it looking at the pencil of lines through $r_1$ but it doesn't work. Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: We can write the equation of $C$ as $y^2 = (x^3 - 1)(x^3 + 1)$. The cubic curve $y^2 = x^3 - 1$ cuts out $r_0+r_2+r_4$ and I'm fairly certain (haven't checked all details) that $y^2 = x^3 + 1$ cuts out $r_1 + r_3 + r_5$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Ok in this way you have shown that $D = r_3+r_5$, haven't you? Now, what about the linear system, do you suggest to choose a pencil of cubics like $y^2=x^3+a,a\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I think you want to look at the full range of plane cubics and examine what they cut out on $\mathcal C$. I know that sounds like a lot; I've never been entirely sure what ACGH were really asking for in this problem.